# Laravel relationships attach if not already attached

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Is there a quick way of attaching relationships if they're not already attached. I am using this code to update relations of a model;

```
        if (!empty($request->get('roles')) && is_array($request->get('roles'))) {
            $message->Roles()->attach($request->get('roles'));
        }
        if (!empty($request->get('users')) && is_array($request->get('users'))) {
            $message->Users()->attach($request->get('users'));
        }
```

But I am getting this error which I am this error;

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-41' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `message_user` (`message_id`, `user_id`) values (1, 41), (1, 42), (1, 43), (1, 44), (1, 45), (1, 46), (1, 47), (1, 48), (1, 49), (1, 50))

I want to avoid going through a very long list of array check which users are not already attached and attaching them. Also let me know if this is the only way.

I am thinking something like;

```
$message->Users()->attachIfNotAttached($request->get('users'));
```

Comment: MySQL supports `INSERT IGNORE`, but I don't think laravel does too.

Comment: I think the only solution is check whether the relationship exists for each user before attaching.

Comment: What is stored in `$request->get('users')`? user IDs?

Comment: $request->get('users') is an array of a list of users ids like [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50] from the example above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this might work:

Get the IDs that are already attached:

```
$attachedIds = $message->Users()->whereIn('id', $request->get('users'))->pluck('id');
```

Remove the attached IDs from the request array:

```
$newIds = array_diff($request->get('users'), $attachedIds);
```

Attach the new IDs:

```
$message->Users()->attach($newIds);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 153):

Laravel has built-in method for this - [syncWithoutDetaching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
$message->Users()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->get('users'));
```

Comment: This is the better answer

Comment: WAY better answer. The method should have an alias, `syncUnique()` or something.  `syncWithoutDetaching` is not exactly intuitive as to its effect.

Comment: this has notihng to do with the OP question, this syncs but OP wants attach

Comment: @behz4d This does exactly what OP wants. It attaches all users from the request to the message that are not attached yet. The "WithoutDetaching" part makes sure no users that are not included in the requests get detached.

Comment: This is the best answer so far

Comment: This may be a cleaner approach, but **appears** to be slower because`syncWithoutDetaching` appears to do individual database writes per pivot insert. `attach([1,2,3])` only does one insert. I have not benchmarked this, purely my observations.

Comment: There's a notable limitation with Laravel's sync methods in that they don't support extra pivot data, but attach does.So if you have a pivot table with an extra column, using`syncWithoutDetaching` isn't an option unfrtunatly. Instead you'd have to follow the accepted answer.

Comment: This works perfect!!, and its true, from the Laravel documentation you can not see this

Comment: Agree with @Sk446, I need updating pivot column value, but with this method, it's not updating

Comment: for the record, if you look into the code this is the same as ->sync([ {values} ], false)

Comment: I sometimes get duplicates with this method, wondering if there is a method that merges with the existing pivots

Answer (score 20):

Using `syncWithoutDetaching` or `sync([arr], false)` looks cleaner in code, but **performs 25x slower** than `attach()`. This is because it checks each id and performs individual database inserts per item.

I'd suggest building upon [Paul Spiegel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356606/laravel-relationships-attach-if-not-already-attached/47141415#answer-45358330) by extending eloquent or creating a new method on your model class.

In my use case I have a `Feed` class and a `Post` class linked by a many to many pivot. I added the following method to my Feed class.

```
public function attachUniquePosts($ids)
{
    $existing_ids = $this->posts()->whereIn('posts.id', $ids)->pluck('posts.id');
    $this->posts()->attach($ids->diff($existing_ids));
}
```

- Attaching 20 posts to a feed using `syncWithoutDetaching()` took on average
  0.107s
- Attaching 20 posts to a feed using
  `attachUniquePosts()` took on average 0.004s

Comment: detach missing elements in $ids?

Comment: Yep, keep in mind that attach makes just a DB "insert" statement. And syncWithoutDeatach makes a "select" to check if exists and then an "insert", so x2 queries

Answer (score 0):

Info: It seems that `syncWithoutDetaching()` is not working on Amazon Aurora MySQL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32833129)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the detach to be sure and then you can use the attach like this function:

```
$handleUserMoving = function ($message) use($user) {
        $message->Users()->detach($user);
        if (!$message->Users()->where('users.id', $user->id)->exists()) 
        {
            $message->Users()->attach($user);
        }
};
$message->Users()->each($handleUserMoving);
```